# Windows 10 internal webcam doesn't start

Tags: windows-10, webcam

I have a webcam but recently it doesn't work. It returns:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwSzR.png)

But I have the control lamp is lightened.

I have tried to uninstall the device in the device manager. But first I have two devices that shows up:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JziQj.png)

And, second, it doesn't change anything when I reboot. I searched for driver updates but nothing came up.

```
Webcam Name:    USB2.0 HD IR UVC WebCam
Quality Rating: 0
Built-in Microphone:    None
Built-in Speaker:   None
Frame rate: 6 FPS
Stream Type:    video
Image Mode: grayscale
Webcam MegaPixels:  0.92 MP
Webcam Resolution:  1280×720
Video Standard: HD
Aspect Ratio:   1.78
PNG File Size:  33.36 kB
JPEG File Size: 19.34 kB
Bitrate:    113.82 kB/s
Number of Colors:   182
Average RGB Color:  
 
Lightness:  20.39%
Luminosity: 20.39%
Brightness: 20.39%
Hue:    0°
Saturation: 0%
```

Comment: What is the computer? If Asus, try the F10 button which is also camera off/on ([link](https://www.asus.com/me-en/support/FAQ/109836/))

Answer (score 0):

What I would do first is go to the device manufacturer website to find the driver. Next I'd remove *both* of the webcams and reboot. If the camera is working, Windows should detect it, and install a driver it thinks suitable. If it doesn't work after that, I'd try installing a new driver.